# Rails exists? Case insensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exists, case-insensitive

```
Model.exists?("lower(email) = ?", params[:email].downcase)
```

Returns error: `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)):`

Is it possible to do a `exists?` with a case insensitive match?

Comment: You're misreading the error, and you should [look at the documentation for proper usage of `exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class)

Comment: you'd rather lowercase before storing in db

Comment: @sjagr - Yeah. Youre right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

```
Model.exists?(["lower(email) = ?", params[:email].downcase])
```

It's looking for a single argument but you're providing two. Using the array form and the find-style conditional should get what you need.

Answer (score 9):

You also can do like this:

```
Model.where("lower(email) = ?",params[:email].downcase).exists?
```